# Initializing a session from another webapp in java

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

i am making an interface upgrade on a project that is currently used, so what i want is to be able to initialize a session on the upgraded project once a user logs in the older application.

The idea is that in time some features will be ported to another view technology and when the user clicks on a ported feature it will take him to the new application but right now i am stuck on this session creation on the new application.

I have tried to send a redirect from the older app security filter class (it's the class that creates the user session and verifies some parameters) but i get an java.lang.IllegalStateException that says Cannot call sendRedirect()  after response has been committed

So is there a way to initialize a new session once a user logs in the older app ?

If it's not possible could you advise me on how to proceed to make the two applications communicate ? Basically i want once the user is logged in the old application to log him in the new one automatically

Thanks

Comment: There is your code missing, but yes, you can do it. All depends how you manage your user sessions. If you can control the requests of both apps, you can *re-create* the session in the new app. Just send a *login request* from the old app to the new. When catched in the new one create a new user session with desired parameters, after that, the redirect will work without problems

Comment: Until the whole application is migrated the requests will only come on the old application. The idea is to offer users new pages where the migration is over and that is why i want to redirect them to the new app.

The login request should be sent as a forward or redirect ? I am doing this from backend since there is the class that logs in the user in the old app. I am not at my work pc right now but if it helps i will post the code Monday. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Posting your code will help you to find an answer. If you can identify the old app requests **AND** you can modify the code in the new app, you won't have much problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Until the whole application is migrated the requests will only come on the old application. The idea is to offer users new pages where the migration is over and that is why i want to redirect them to the new app. The login request should be sent as a forward or redirect ? I am doing this from backend since there is the class that logs in the user in the old app.

I have designed and implemented a similar requirement in the past and maybe it will be of help.

1. The 2 applications were in the same sub-domain so that cookies (and especially session cookies) of one flows in the request to the other.
2. One of the servers was the 'login' server which authenticates the user. In your case, it would be the older version of your application.
3. We did not do back end redirection (though that was one of the approaches considered).
4. When a user session was created by the old application, we made an entry in a db table in a schema shared by the 2 apps. This entry contained the session-id, a unique user id, a flag called 'IS_ACCESSED' (which's need I will explain soon), another flag  called 'IS_VALID' (which is set to false on logout), a secondary session-id (which I will explain below) and a creation timestamp.
5. Features developed on the new application will have links pointing to the new application itself. Clicking on these links will take the user to the new application.
6. When a request reaches the new application, a Filter first checks for a valid session of that application. If it does not find one, it then checks for the session cookie of the old application (remember all cookies flow to both apps, both being in the same sub domain). If it finds a cookie of the old application, it retrieves the cookie value and accesses the db table to find if a session-cookie with that value has been put in by the old application. If it does, it retrieves the associated user id, creates its own session (in the new app), loads basic session data (user profile info) onto that session and then allows the user to the requested page in the new app. It also updates the record with its own session-id (the column secondary_session_id) so that the record contains a pair of session-ids

Basically the session is recreated in the second app. On reading the cookie value first time, the 'IS_ACCESSED' value is set to true to avoid a 'replay' scenario using the old session cookie.

Also the IS_VALID is marked to false once the user logs out. You could use the flag to check if the user has logged out from the primary session and invalidate the secondary (for single logout use cases)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. We ended up using the basic httpRequest redirect and for us it did the job.

Comment: np, just curious - how did you ensure that only authorized users can access the new app?

Comment: I send some request parameters that are checked, basically the 2 Security Filters are the same just that in SecurityFilter1 i send a redirect with request parameters to the new application and in SecurityFilter2 i just send a redirect to the older app.